# l can't remove the last search when you search for a new word

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I'm building a website using javascript and I'm requesting from API,
If you write a word into the search field, the definition is returned to the user interface. However, l can't remove the last search when you search for a new word. I want to remove the last search when I search for a new word, but I'm not sure how to do it,  it keeps stacking [like in this image first search was about police word then fact word the police definitions displayed even if l search another thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSMlo.png)

```
 <input type="text" onchange="input()"  id="input-word" placeholder="Search" />
```

```
.then((data) => {
        const result = data.entries['0'].lexemes['0']
        result.senses.map(arr => {
            const div = document.createElement('div')
            containerSection.appendChild(div)
            const para = document.createElement('p')
            para.innerHTML = arr.definition;
            div.appendChild(para)

        });
```

```
 let input = document.getElementById('input-word').value
    
        getResult(input)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just clear the `innerHTML` of the container element first

```
 .then((data) => {
    containerSection.innerHTML=""; // clears previous content
    ...
```

Comment: Thank You a lot it worked and l put it in the input function instead .then((data) => {